# Microphone not working - HP C1030 - Fresh Mint installation

Tags: linux-mint, audio, microphone, hp

I recently installed Mint 21.1 on my HP Elite c1030 laptop. Everything works smoothly,
except for the microphone. The internal mic shows up at PulseAudio Volume Control, but
the bar doesn't "bounce" at all, it's like no sound is being detected from the internal
mic.

I tried unmixing and setting the right channel to 0, in case the mic was not stereo,
but that didn't work. I updated to Kernel 5.19.0-41-generic, still nothing.

Not sure what to do at this point, I'd appreciate any help!